# Get map from retrofit query

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have JSON that I get using retrofit

```
[{  
  "id":"1",
  "name":"name",
  "fields_json":{  
     "f1":"value1",
     "f2":"value2",
     "f3":"value3"
  }
},{  
  "id":"2",
  "name":"name2",
  "fields_json":{  
     "f1":"value1",
     "f2":"value2",
     "f3":"value3"
  }
}]
```

I want get List of Person(long id, String name, Map fields)

How I may get fields_json as Map in this class?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your json a bit,  so you can use special response classes
{"persons":[{id":"1","name":"name", ...}  ] }

```
public class Response {

     @SerializedName("persons")
     @Expose
     public ArrayList<Person> persones;
}

public class Person {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("fields_json")
    @Expose
    public FieldsJson fieldsJson;

}

public class FieldsJson {

    @SerializedName("f1")
    @Expose
    public String f1;
    @SerializedName("f2")
    @Expose
    public String f2;
    @SerializedName("f3")
    @Expose
    public String f3;
}
```

and set this class as response

```
@POST("/url")
Call<Response> getPersones(
        ....
);
```

So, if you wish You can describe public fieldsJson as Map

```
Map<String, Object> fieldsJson
```

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be added as a Map object. 
Instead you need to create another java class that contains the f1-f3 variables.
Then add this new class as a variable with the name of fields_json to your current class.

Comment: but f1,f2,f3 - dynamically keys